# Writing a custom cell format containing a double quote?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want Excel to format my time values such that "72 minutes and 53 seconds" is displayed as `72'53"`.

In custom cell format lingo, this is probably close to`[m]'ss"`, but I don't know what to do with that last double quote.  As it stands, simply inputting that format leads to an error dialog.

The question: What do I input to get a literal `"` shown as part of the cell format?

Excel version I'm using is "Version 1808" (from Office 365).

Edit: I tried `\` but these escape characters are apparently different across system locales.  (Mine was Japanese and a backslash didn't solve the problem.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `\` character in front of reserved characters.

```
[m]'ss\"
```

[image]

Note: This assumes you're using Excel in a locale where `\` is designated the escape character, such as English.  The OP has clarified in the comments they're using Excel in the Japanese locale where the same escape character is  `!`.  The format for them is therefore `[m]'ss!"`.

Comment: Strange, that exact format copied and pasted doesn't work in my version of Excel.  It might be locale sensitive because \ (ascii 92 backslash) in my UI renders as a JPY symbol.

Comment: If your locale is not English, it might help if you noted that in your question.

Comment: My bad, didn't think it'd be locale dependent.  I added an edit to your answer so I can accept it, but it's waiting peer review because my rep is too low.

Comment: The edit is now approved.